# useMediaQuery and gatsby cause UI blink

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, gatsby

I'm using the useMediaQuery in this manner

```
const IndexPage: React.FC<PageProps<PageData, PageContext>> = (props) => {
  const web = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up("md"));
  const mobile = !web;
  return (
    <main>
      ...
    </main>
  );
 };
```

But it causes rerender, as useMediaQuery returns its value twice. I cannot use the {noSrr: false} option, as I'm using gatsby.

How should I handle this?